# How to filter out NaN by pydantic

Tags: python, nan, pydantic

How to filter out NaN in pytdantic float validation?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    float_value: float
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `confloat` and set either the higher limit to infinity or the lower limit to minus infinity. As all numeric comparisons with NaN return False, that will make pydantic reject NaN, while leaving all other behaviour identical (including parsing, conversion from int to float, ...).

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, confloat

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    float_value: confloat(ge=-float('inf'))
    # or:
    # float_value: confloat(le=float('inf'))
```

Note: you could additionally exclude infinity values by using the `gt` and `lt` arguments of `confloat` instead of `ge` and `le`.

Testing:

```py
m = MySchema(float_value=float('nan'))
```

Output:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MySchema
float_value
  ensure this value is greater than or equal to -inf (type=value_error.number.not_ge; limit_value=-inf)
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar [feature request](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1779) was raised on pydantic's Github repo.
Maintainers suggest field validation on these models.

```
import maths
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    float_value: float

    @validator('*', pre=True)
    def split_str(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, float):
            if maths.isnan(v):
                raise ValueError("value can't be Not-a-Number (NaN)")
            return v
        return v
```

Note that in [pydantic **v2**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/)  this solution looks as follows

```
import maths
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    float_value: float

    @field_validator('*', mode='before')
    def split_str(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, float):
            if maths.isnan(v):
                raise ValueError("value can't be Not-a-Number (NaN)")
            return v
        return v
```

Comment: typo at mats -> maths. This approach won't allow you to use normal floats in another fields, moreover it will also try to validate floats provided in other supersets of floats such as "Any" or Unions, which may be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

The up to date answer for pydantic versions >= 1.10 is to use `confloat` and set its `allow_inf_nan` accordingly:

```
class Finite(BaseModel):
    value: confloat(allow_inf_nan=False)
```

With that, the arguments `float("inf")`, `-float("inf")`, `float("nan")`, and `-float("inf")` will result in an `ValidationError`.

See the [documentation of `confloat`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#arguments-to-confloat).

Answer (score 0):

Define your custom type for validations, is well documented at [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types):

```
class NoNanFloat(float):
    
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate
        
    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        # you can ommit this method
        field_schema.update(
            examples=['24.2,15.2'],
        )

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, float):
            raise TypeError('float required')
        if v!=v: # you can use here also maths.isnan(v):
            raise ValueError("value can't be Not-a-Number (NaN)")
        return cls(v)

    def __repr__(self):
        # you can also ommit this method, but it looks good when printing. 
        return f'NoNanFloat({super().__repr__()})'
    
class MySchema(BaseModel):
    no_nan_float_value: NoNanFloat
    other_float_value: float
    other: Any
```

This approach has many advantages, as it allows you to have two types of "floats" depending on your needs, so you can have some allowing nan and others that doesn't.

I also allows you to have the "Any" type accepting nans, and unions of types behaving as expected.